# Enabling the NSCopying protocol in a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nscopying

I have a class that has been derived from NSObject. How can copy be enabled like [object copy]?

This is for an iPhone application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple's documentation on the NSCopying protocol can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying).